# Enum with getting subset

Tags: java, enum

I just wrote this but I'm not sure if this is good practice.  Can someone give me advice as to whether it's good or how I can do better or even it's bad code?

The point is that I need a sub List-array-set of the enum.  The `SubType.ELSE` shall have another name in reality (I know that was a bad choice, but it's for pointing it out).

```
public enum ContentType {
    TITLE("$$title$$",SubType.MAIL),
    BODY("$$body$$",SubType.MAIL),
    MESSAGE("$$message$$",SubType.MAIL),
    EVENTS("$$events$$",SubType.ELSE);

    private final String replaceWord;
    private final SubType subType;

    private ContentType(String replaceWord, SubType subType ) {
        this.replaceWord = replaceWord;
        this.subType = subType;
    }

    public String getReplaceWord() {
        return replaceWord;
    }

    private SubType getSubType() {
        return subType;
    }

    public static List<ContentType> values(SubType subType) {
        List<ContentType> subList = new ArrayList<ContentType>();
        for (ContentType type : ContentType.values()) {
            if (type.getSubType() == subType) {
                subList.add(type);
            }
        }
        return subList;
    }
}

enum SubType {
    MAIL,
    ELSE;
}
```

Comment: I would not complicate the code with hashmap/enummap/etc caches as the answers suggest. It seems [premature optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/80092/36726).

Comment: The correct way is to avoid for/while/loops when you have an enum and to use EnumSet.

Comment: @BlessedGeek thx for the comment, you can see in mine own answer where I did put the revised code that it was taken in account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219219/java-subtype-enums-or-subclass/68579907#68579907

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest two changes to `values(SubType)`:

- Return a `Set` instead of a `List`.
- Prepare all the possible results at class-loading time, so that `values(SubType)` could be accomplished by a simple lookup.  The code is slightly more complicated, but the runtime performance should be better.

```
private static final Map<SubType, Set<ContentType>> BY_SUBTYPE;
static {
    BY_SUBTYPE = new HashMap<SubType, Set<ContentType>>();
    for (SubType subType : SubType.values()) {
        BY_SUBTYPE.put(subType, new TreeSet<ContentType>());
    }
    for (ContentType type : ContentType.values()) {
        BY_SUBTYPE.get(type.getSubType()).add(type);
    }
    for (SubType subType : BY_SUBTYPE.keySet()) {
        // Make Set<ContentType> values immutable
        BY_SUBTYPE.put(subType, Collections.unmodifiableSet(BY_SUBTYPE.get(subType)));
    }
}

public static Set<ContentType> values(SubType subType) {
    // Returns an unmodifiable view of a SortedSet
    return BY_SUBTYPE.get(subType);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the feedback and the suggestions, I'll refactor mine code following your suggestions.

Answer (score 10):

I agree mostly with @200_success' answer, though for simplicity and maintainability I do suggest you to use the following, which is only possible in Java 8. It functionally does the same as @200_success' answer.

The code with explanation below:

```
public enum ContentType {
    TITLE("$$title$$", SubType.MAIL),
    BODY("$$body$$", SubType.MAIL),
    MESSAGE("$$message$$", SubType.MAIL),
    EVENTS("$$events$$", SubType.DEFAULT);

    private static final Map<SubType, Set<ContentType>> SETS_BY_SUBTYPE;
    static {
        SETS_BY_SUBTYPE = Arrays.stream(values())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        contentType -> contentType.getSubType(),
                        Collectors.toSet()
                ));
    }

    private final String replaceWord;
    private final SubType subType;

    private ContentType(final String replaceWord, final SubType subType) {
        this.replaceWord = replaceWord;
        this.subType = subType;
    }

    public String getReplaceWord() {
        return replaceWord;
    }

    private SubType getSubType() {
        return subType;
    }

    public static Set<ContentType> values(final SubType subType) {
        return SETS_BY_SUBTYPE.get(subType);
    }
}

enum SubType {
    MAIL,
    DEFAULT;
}
```

To explain it more precisely, consider only the code that generates the mapping:

```
SETS_BY_SUBTYPE = Arrays.stream(values())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                contentType -> contentType.getSubType(),
                Collectors.toSet()
        ));
```

What it does is:

1. Obtain a `ContentType[]`.
2. Convert the array to a `Stream<ContentType>`, this is the starting point of functional programming.
3. Collect the stream in a data structure, here we want to have a `Map<SubType, Set<ContentType>>`.
4. The unoverloaded version of `Collectors.groupingBy` groups elements on a certain property, here it is `contentType.getSubType()`. The caveat with the default version is that it returns a `List<ContentType>` whereas we want a `Set<ContentType>`.
5. So we need to supply a `downstream` argument to the method, which in this case becomes a `Collectors.toSet()` downstream collector.

Another name suggestion would be to change `SubType.ELSE` to `SubType.DEFAULT`, where *default* semantically means that it does not belong to something else.

Other small remarks are about the horizontal white space, please be consistent there:

- Your enum declarations were missing one between the arguments.
- In one method there was too much horizontal whitespace.

I personally value horizontal whitespace and consistent looking code quite a bit as it in my opinion indicates how seriously you are working with your code.

Since the answer of @chillworld included using an `EnumMap`, which is argubly better, at least for improved performance, we can construct it with the following:

```
private static final EnumMap<SubType, Set<ContentType>> SETS_BY_SUBTYPE;
static {
    SETS_BY_SUBTYPE = Arrays.stream(values())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ContentType::getSubType,
                    () -> new EnumMap<>(SubType.class),
                    Collectors.toSet()
            ));
}
```

Here we explicitely specify an `EnumMap` over the general `Map` interface and to obtain it we use the third parameter of `Collectors.groupingBy`, which is one that takes a `mapFactory` as argument, which means that you need to provide the map yourself here.

Another difference is that we here use a method reference, `ContentType::getSubType`, over `contentType -> contentType.getSubType()` for improved readability.

Comment: Thx for the feedback, but I can't do anything with it cause I'm obligatory to use java 6, of course not of free will :D.

Answer (score 10):

Oke after reading all your suggestions I refactored the code to this :

```
public enum ContentType {

    TITLE("$$title$$"),
    BODY("$$body$$"),
    MESSAGE("$$message$$"),
    EVENTS("$$events$$");

    private static final Map<SubType, Set<ContentType>> BY_SUBTYPE;

    private final String replaceWord;

    static {
        //Get a map with key's all the values of the SubType class.
        BY_SUBTYPE = new EnumMap<SubType, Set<ContentType>>(SubType.class);
        //Fill the key for MAIL.
        BY_SUBTYPE.put(SubType.MAIL, Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.range(TITLE, MESSAGE)));
        //Fill the key for DEFAULT.
        BY_SUBTYPE.put(SubType.DEFAULT, Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(EVENTS)));
    }

    private ContentType(String replaceWord) {
        this.replaceWord = replaceWord;
    }

    public static Set<ContentType> values(SubType subType) {
        // Returns an unmodifiable view of a SortedSet
        return BY_SUBTYPE.get(subType);
    }

    public String getReplaceWord() {
        return replaceWord;
    }

    public enum SubType {
        MAIL,
        DEFAULT;
    }

}
```

Explication :

It started with netbeans suggesting to use the [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).
After some reading about [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) and [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), I'll come up with this.Don't use that a lot :)

`BY_SUBTYPE = new EnumMap<SubType, Set<ContentType>>(SubType.class);` :
We create an [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) whitch has as keys all the values of SubType.
You can't create more keys and null keys are not allowed.

`EnumSet.range(TITLE, MESSAGE);` :
This gives us a [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) witch contains every Enum value from `TITLE` to `MESSAGE`.

`EnumSet.of(EVENTS);` 
This gives us a [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) witch contains only `EVENTS`.

Refactoring is more difficult then @200_succes his answer, but I don't have to iterate 2 times over the SubType and one time over the ContentType.

**Edit :**

I did have to move the subtype to the EnumClass itself, otherwise I couldn't reach it from outside the Enum.

Comment: I advice against using `EnumSet.range(TITLE, MESSAGE);` my experience is that it's just a matter of time before someone (most likely you) change the order of the enums, and then you do not want to use code that depends on a specific enum ordering. Trust me, it has happened before...

Comment: I could use the EnumSet.of(TITLE,BODY,MESSAGE);

Answer (score 5):

I was just playing with this and came up with this rather neat (IMHO) solution so I thought I should post.

Essentially, I let the `SubType` `enums` hold a `Set` of the `ContentType` that link to them. You then do your query on the sub types.

```
enum SubType {
  MAIL,
  ELSE;
  // This way breaks! We are trying to access the ContentType before it is initialised.
  // Set<ContentType> contentTypes = EnumSet.noneOf(ContentType.class);
  Set<ContentType> contentTypes = new HashSet<>();

  public void addContentType(ContentType add) {
    contentTypes.add(add);
  }

  public Set<ContentType> getContentTypes() {
    return contentTypes;
  }
}

public enum ContentType {
  TITLE("$$title$$", SubType.MAIL),
  BODY("$$body$$", SubType.MAIL),
  MESSAGE("$$message$$", SubType.MAIL),
  EVENTS("$$events$$", SubType.ELSE);

  private final String replaceWord;
  private final SubType subType;

  private ContentType(String replaceWord, SubType subType) {
    this.replaceWord = replaceWord;
    this.subType = subType;
    subType.addContentType(this);
  }

  public String getReplaceWord() {
    return replaceWord;
  }

  private SubType getSubType() {
    return subType;
  }

}
```